# Is it possible to have a generic Addition method

Tags: c#, generics

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How to cast an object into its type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031821/how-to-cast-an-object-into-its-type)
>   [Solution for overloaded operator constraint in .NET generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147646/solution-for-overloaded-operator-constraint-in-net-generics)

Hi All,

Is it possible to have a generic Addition method?
something like:

```
public void Add<T>(T a, T b)
{
    T c = a + b;//Error
}
```

Actually operands '+' can not be applied to Type T. Is there any way around?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031821/how-to-cast-an-object-into-its-type/1031834#1031834

Comment: Is this really a generic scenario? or is there an abstract object(s) that have that (+) addition logic?

Comment: See my answer in that question for a solution for user-defined types. Other answers discuss how it can be done for integral value types.

Comment: Sigh, if that question is an exact duplicate, maybe it should be titled as such, or edited so that it is clear.  Without reading the answers I would have NO CLUE that it was asking almost the same thing.  No wonder he couldn't find it.